# Google Admin SDK in Calendar Audit Activity

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I have use google-admin-sdk for calendar activity reports. I've researched some responses and I didn't understand some parameters. https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/calendar you can review this document. 
According to Google these parameters are the start and end time of the event but I don't know where the 11-digit timestamp is used?

[image]

Comment: Timestamps in JavaScript are count of milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.

Comment: I know but I tried these numbers and getting 1972 years. We are in 2020 :)

Answer (score 1):

The two parameters are used to indicate the **start time** and the **end time** of an event.

- The `start_time` parameter is the number in seconds representing the **start time** for the event.
- The `end_time` parameter is the number in seconds representing the **end time** for the event.

In order to obtain the date you can either:

1. use the following code snippet:

```
function findDate() {
  var seconds = "NO_OF_SECONDS";
  var date = new Date(seconds * 1000);
  console.log(date);
}
```

2. use an online converter which will give you the an approximate date for the number of seconds mentioned;

Comment: I see but I created meeting event on calendar at 2020-02-17. Well, it will start at the 15:00 and end 16:00.  I need two responses , start_time and end_time. I have already them. But I don't know how to use them ? What I should do with 11-digit timestamp ?

Comment: Hello @AbdullahSerhatİNCE, the event creation time is different from both of these parameters. And if you subtract both of these number, the result is `1800` which if you transform these in minutes, it results into 30 minutes. What do you mean by "I don't know how to use them. What I should do with 11-digit timestamp?"? Cheers!

Comment: Thank you @ale13 for interest. Actually, I will write the microservice with node.js. The service should check the google calendar every day, get the events related to the meeting and know what time they will start and end. I did not know what to do with the start_time and end_time parameters I have. Because I tried many things, but a logical date value did not return.

Comment: Hello @AbdullahSerhatİNCE, I have updated my answer and I hope this solves your question :) Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, as you said it shows the meeting time like 30 minutes.

Comment: @AbdullahSerhatİNCE yep, that's it! Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving your problem :) See also [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Cheers!